# Plotting a raster stack with ggplot2

Tags: raster, r, ggplot2, plot

My aim is to plot a rasterstack as a single image using ggplot2. First, I apply `ggplot` on a single layer raster using the following code:

```
#Load packages
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

#Create a random raster layer
set.seed(11)
r <- raster(nrows = 10, ncols = 10, res = 30, xmn = 267195, xmx = 267375, ymn = 4016985, ymx = 4017135)
r <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r), min = -10000, max = 10000))
crs(r) <- "+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
plot(r) #Produce simple plot

rdf <- as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE) #Convert raster to data.frame
names(rdf)[3] <- 'magnitude' #Name value column
head(rdf)
```

Now I apply `gglpot()`

```
ggplot(data = rdf)+
  geom_raster(mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, fill=magnitude))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours= rev(terrain.colors(10)), name='Magnitude')
```

It successfully prints. Now I create a raster stack with 10 layers and call this `ndvi`.

```
rr <- lapply(1:10, function(i) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r), min = -10000, max = 10000)))
ndvi <- stack(rr)
crs(ndvi) <- "+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
plot(ndvi)
```

How could I plot this stack using `ggplot2`? Do I create a data.frame but then how do I supply fill argument in `aes()` and `facet_wrap()`?

Comment: How would you imagine that you could use all 10 layers in a single graph? Do you want a set of 10 smaller graphs, or somehow combine all 10 into an image?

Comment: I would prefer 10 graphs into one image using facet_warp() etc. But it would be interesting to learn how to to produce a set of 10 smaller graphs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `scale_fill_gradientn` to specify the fill, and `facet_wrap` should pick the colours from there:

1. If you have `rasterVis` package installed, you can use `gplot` function to create the `ggplot` object

```
library(rasterVis)
gplot(ndvi) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(terrain.colors(225))) +
  coord_equal()
```

2. Otherwise, you can construct the data yourself, which is basely what `gplot` function does

```
coords <- xyFromCell(ndvi, seq_len(ncell(ndvi)))
ndvi <- stack(as.data.frame(getValues(ndvi)))
names(ndvi) <- c('value', 'variable')

ndvi <- cbind(coords, ndvi)
ggplot(ndvi) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(terrain.colors(225))) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is what I needed. One more thing, how can I plot it layer by layer where each layer is a separate plot?

Comment: You could apply a function (that plots a single layer) over the layer names. So, each time you use the layer name to extract the corresponding layer and create a ggplot object. This means you will end up with a list of ggplot objects.

Comment: Ok thanks. This helps.